# ERROR when I tried to Import a Class React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning react native, and I ran into this problem, I'm trying to export a Class to another Screen, but "View config getter callback for component... must be a function" appears, if anyone can help me I'll be extremely grateful, I'll print de code below. Should I change the Class for a function? Is there any other way to export this code as a Class?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Block, Text, Input, theme } from 'galio-framework';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');


export default class menuLateral extends React.Component {
  renderSearch = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const iconCamera = <Icon size={16} color={theme.COLORS.MUTED} name="zoom-in" family="material" />

    return (
      <Input
        right
        color="black"
        style={styles.search}
        iconContent={iconCamera}
        placeholder="What are you looking for?"
        onFocus={() => navigation.navigate('Pro')}
      />
    )
  }
  
  renderTabs = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <Block row style={styles.tabs}>
        <Button shadowless style={[styles.tab, styles.divider]} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Pro')}>
          <Block row middle>
            <Icon name="grid" family="feather" style={{ paddingRight: 8 }} />
            <Text size={16} style={styles.tabTitle}>Categories</Text>
          </Block>
        </Button>
        <Button shadowless style={styles.tab} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Pro')}>
          <Block row middle>
            <Icon size={16} name="camera-18" family="GalioExtra" style={{ paddingRight: 8 }} />
            <Text size={16} style={styles.tabTitle}>Best Deals</Text>
          </Block>
        </Button>
      </Block>
    )
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  home: {
    width: width,    
  },
  search: {
    height: 48,
    width: width - 32,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },

  tabs: {
    marginBottom: 24,
    marginTop: 10,
    elevation: 4,
  },
  tab: {
    backgroundColor: theme.COLORS.TRANSPARENT,
    width: width * 0.50,
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    height: 24,
    elevation: 0,
  },
  tabTitle: {
    lineHeight: 19,
    fontWeight: '300'
  },
  divider: {
    borderRightWidth: 0.3,
    borderRightColor: theme.COLORS.MUTED,
  },

})
```

Answer (score 1):

React components have to start with a capital letter so that's the first issue.  Second issue is that react components need a render function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, I didn't expected that. I corrected the first issue you said, but the second one I thought that the "renderSearch" and "renderTabs" were considered a render function, sorry if thats a dumb question, I'm learning as I said before. Should I create another render?

Comment: if you are only starting react now my advise would be to not use class components and only use functional components as they are much simpler and better.  

For class components you do actually have to have a render function but it looks like this component is hooking into another library so I'm not entirely sure what render tabs or render search do but they are likely supposed to be plugged in as props inside a component in your render function.